# Wireframe Consistent Thickness

Tags: modeling, modifiers, wireframe

I require a consistent thickness for 3D printing a wire-framed model. The wire-frame modifier isn't sufficient as thicknesses are inconsistent. Ideally, the wire-frame would consist of 'pipes' with a circular profile which could be specified with exact dimensions. Is this possible?

[image]
Wireframe modifier gives an inconsistent thickness

[image]
I want to wireframe this model with a consistent thickness

[image]
Bevel curve doesn't work great either

Comment: Have you tried the [Wireframe Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html)?

Comment: Yes I've tried wireframe modifier, I've also tried converting the mesh to a curve and 'thickening' this by increasing bevel depth. All options give an inconsistent 'pipe' thickness.